# Is there an Android equivalent of Linux command "xinput --list"?

Tags: shell

I'd like to disable the physical keyboard and touchpad of my 2-in-1 touchscreen laptop when I use it as a tablet running on Android-x86, and so far I've managed to disable the keyboard by naming it in the file `/android-7.1-rc2/system/etc/excluded-input-devices.xml`, which is called `AT Translated Set 2 keyboard`.

But I couldn't properly name the touchpad :-(
I guess I need Android equivalent of Linux command `xinput --list` (if something like this exists at all).

Any ideas/suggestions please?

Comment: Since Android-x86 is installed alongside Linux on the same laptop, using the name given by the linux command `xinput --list` (ELAN1200:00 04F3:3058 Touchpad) worked in Android-x86 as well ! :-) But I might keep the question still to see if there's a similar command in Android...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Enter the command `su root` to gain root access.
2. Enter the command `getevent -p` to see a list of devices - which will match and even provide more detailed info than the linux command `xinput --list`